# How to reset array object when it reaches certain size?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, browser, buffer

I have incoming logs coming from server using socket.io , I am receiving around 5000 messages in one minute that is freezing the browser and restricting user to make any action on application. Is there any way to set the buffer size of array `$scope.event` to certain limit like `5Mb` and once it reaches that limit empty array object out and start pushing new messages ?

ctrl.js

```
$scope.event = [];

socket.on('Consumer', function(data) {
    var obj = {
            file: $scope.filename,
            data: data
        }
    $scope.event.push({
        id: $scope.event.length,
        value: data
    });
});
```

Comment: if you're going to use non-technical terms like "roll out" you have to tell us what it means//

Comment: it means reset array to `[]` and start pushing new incoming data

Comment: Seems like a simple task. Have you tried if (myarray.length>500) myarray.length = []

Comment: use some server side paging/filtering. Seems if you are willing to dump it all locally then you don't really need it all sent to you in the first place

Comment: Er.. you know what I meant.. coding on my cell phone

Comment: more important is to set size of array size into 5Mb and have condition on it

Comment: My guess is your issue has nothing to do with array size but the amount you are trying to render at a time. There are lots of solutions for limiting rendered data or rendering on demand as well as data store management techniques to purge older data

Comment: @charlietfl Ok, can you please provide best solution to limit data rendering  in my case, because in future we might rendered more messages per minute count.

Comment: can use filter or limitTo in ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm unsure about how you can implement a size limit (in bytes), however if you wanted to put an arbitrary limit in terms of array size you can do something like this:

```
$scope.event = [];

socket.on('Consumer', function(data) {
    var obj = {
            file: $scope.filename,
            data: data
        }
    safelyAdd({
        id: $scope.event.length,
        value: data
    });
});
var limit = 500;
function safelyAdd(element){
  ($scope.event.length >= limit) && $scope.event.length = 0; //reset array if max size reached
  $scope.event.push(element); //then push
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use splice function to remove your old messages in array event. See the documentation : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice

Answer (score 0):

I have answered based on what @charlietfl and @Michele Ricciardi have mentioned in the comments and answers with a bit of how to implement code which I've used when displaying large number of items in the view.It's definitely the rendering part is taking time here for bulk amount.So consider making below changes in your JS and HTML

```
$scope.events = [];

socket.on('Consumer', function(data) {
    var obj = {
            file: $scope.filename,
            data: data
        }
    safelyAdd({
        id: $scope.event.length,
        value: data
    });
});
var limit = 5000;
function safelyAdd(element){
  if($scope.events.length >= limit){ 
     $scope.events =[];//reset array if max size reached..
} 
  $scope.events.push(element); //then push new item..
}
```

You should do something like below in your HTML while rendering this huge data like @charlietfl mentioned in comments by using `limitTo` filter provided by angular itself.

```
<div>
 <!-- lts display 500 records at a time so ng-repeat evaluates only 500 at once in the entire list -->
<p ng-repeat="event in events track by $index | limitTo:500"> </p>
</div>
```

Comment: you have assigned `limit` variable value `5000` i believe that is type it should be 500 ?

Comment: You said you are receiving 5000 msgs so I thought we will have 5000 events so after that we will reset our events array.As far as display is concerned we are displaying 500 /5000 at a time.You can change this numbers as you like to though.

Comment: i have a  function that is converting string to bytes so i have variable `$scope.dynamic` that has value of bytes lets assume `5000 bytes` how i will apply to your logic to check if limit is greater than $scope.dynamic` reset array ?